# Upgrade Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 error: Fetching the file failed

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, update-manager, 20.04

I get this problem when I'm trying to upgrade from ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04:

```
$sudo do-release-upgrade -d
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [1,554 B]
Err Upgrade tool
  404  Not Found [IP: 59.80.44.48 80]
Fetched 1,554 B in 0s (0 B/s)
WARNING:root:file 'focal.tar.gz' missing
Failed to fetch
Fetching the upgrade failed. There may be a network problem.
```

Here are the commands of what I had run so far:

```
$sudo apt-get update --fix-missing; sudo dpkg --configure -a; sudo apt-get install -f; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade; sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-keyring
```

Here is my source list:

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#                            OFFICIAL UBUNTU REPOS                             #
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#


###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

The network is OK (I'm using AWS China), so what should I do to fix it?

Comment: Does the apt-get commands work as expected? Could you pleas update the question with the output of `sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: It's the AWS China ec2's private DNS fault, after I changed the DNS nameserver to 1.1.1.1, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. By changing all the `us.archive`s to `cn.archive`s, I finally managed to upgrade to 20.04 LTS. (PS I am living in mainland China.)

Answer (score 0):

It downloads via http from IP "59.80.44.48 80". Ping it to see if you can reach it...

```
ping 59.80.44.48
```

or write it to your browser:

```
http://59.80.44.48
```

As I did it and :

```
错误
您所请求的网址（URL）无法获取
```

it is indeed 404 cannot be reached

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

change `.cn.archive to .us.archive` ...

and try again

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working either. After I change to the US mirror and re-run the commands: apt update && apt upgrade, the error is the same: 404  Not Found [IP: 59.80.44.48 80] What am I missing?

Comment: Update: It’s the AWS China ec2's private DNS fault,  after I changed the DNS nameserver to 1.1.1.1, everything worked fine.